# define DEBUG symbol on a VS2010 Website?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web, debug-symbols

I can't find where this setting is

```
#if !DEBUG
//            some code
#endif
```

when I change the configuration dropdown from debug to release, I see no changes in my code, which suggests that my DEBUG symbol is not defined

EDIT

I do not see the setting in the Buid screen as Mark suggests:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here? Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the properties on the project (the website), go to the Build tab and make sure `Define DEBUG constant` is checked.

This setting can be changed for each build configuration.

Comment: please see my edited question. I can't see the setting you are referring to

Answer (score 1):

If Mark's answer doesn't do it, try changing to

```
#ifndef DEBUG

 /* ... */

#endif
```

or optionally

```
#if !defined(DEBUG)

 /* ... */

#endif
```

and see if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

In Web.config, change the compilation section to:

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

or

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

Worked for me, but it's annoying there is no option in the build screen.